# t-sql query to get all the rows from Table_A which have at least one matching relatedid in Table_B

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Based on the below tables

```
Table_A

Id  RelatedId
---------------
1   1
1   2
1   3
2   4
2   5
2   2
3   7
3   8
4   9

Table_B

RelatedId  Name
--------------
2          A
3          B
```

I want to get all the rows from Table_A which have at least one matching relatedid in Table_B. The Ids from Table_A that do not have match in Table_B will have single row in the result table.

So output (result table) in this case will be

```
Id  RelatedId
---------------
1   1
1   2
1   3
2   4
2   5
2   2
3   Null
4   Null
```

EDIT: Seems like the question text is confusing for many. So a detailed explanation:

Table_A Id 1 has both 2 and 3 (Related Ids) matching in table_B. So output will have all the rows for 1 from Table_A. Similary Id 2 from Table_A has 2 (Related Id) matching in table_B. So all rows corresponding to 2 from Table_A will be picked up. Since 3 does not have any matching relatedid in table_B it will be displayed but with NULL as relatedid in the results table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with validids as (
 select distinct id 
 from Table_A 
  inner join Table_B on 
   Table_A.relatedid = Table_B.relatedid
)
select 
  id,
  relatedid
from Table_A 
where id in (select id from validids)
union 
select distinct
 id, 
 null
from Table_A
where id not in (select id from validids)
```

Comment: This is more than just an outer join issue.  The results include more information than what would be displayed by a standard outer join.

Comment: yeah, that was my original answer which I undeleted so I could put the real answer in. unfortunately you could all see the answer again whilst I edited it.

Comment: any chance of retracting the -1

Comment: Nice recovery.  I like the new answer.  Sorry, I pulled the -1 trigger.  I'll give it back where I can. There you go, 2-point switch.  :)

Comment: @Chris: Thanks. That gives the desired output. +1 and green check :)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
  Select Distinct Id, Related_Id
  From Table_A 
  Where Related_Id In 
      (Select Related_Id From Table_B)
```

Comment: The above does not give the desired result. I think i was not clear with my explanation. The output has has to have all rows from Table_A if that particular Id has atleast one matching RelatedId in Table_B. 

So in this case from Table_A Id 1 has both 2 and 3 matching in table_B. So output will have all the rows for 1 from Table_A. Similary Id 2 from Table_A has 2 matching in table_B. So all rows corresponding to 2 from Table_A will be picked up. Since 3 does not have any matching relatedid in table_B it will be displayed but with NULL as relatedid in the results table.

Comment: ahh, that was not clear... I will edit to correct.. As you have just articulated it, all you want is the rows from Table_A where the Related ID is in Table_B? Then the amended sql should do the trick

Comment: Actually its not giving the intended result. Can you pls. let me know what is the alias "B" corresponding to in the above query ??

Comment: 'twas typo I needed to delete from editing the first sql, which I failed to delete...  should work now..

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
with IdsWithMatchInB(Id) as (
  select distinct
    Id
  from Table_A
  where Table_A.RelatedId in (
    select Table_B.RelatedId
    from Table_B
  )
)
  select
    Table_A.Id,
    CASE WHEN IdsWithMatchInB.Id IS NULL
         THEN NULL
    ELSE Table_A.RelatedId END AS RelatedId
from Table_A
left outer join IdsWithMatchInB
on IdsWithMatchInB.Id = Table_A.Id
```

Here's another option that avoids DISTINCT by putting the subquery inside the CASE expression:

```
select
  Id,
  case when Id in (
    select Id
    from Table_A as Acopy
    where Acopy.RelatedId in (
      select
        RelatedId 
      from Table_B
    )
  )
  then RelatedId
  else null end as RelatedId
from Table_A;
```

One or the other might be more efficient for your particular data and indexes.